# How do I fix 'Interaction Already Replied' Error on Discord Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

> I've just started making discord bot, and I've successfully registered slash commands. When I run the bot, the slash commands only works a single time, when the slash commands is repeated again it gives me the error code 'InteractionAlreadyReplied'. If you don't seem to understand this error only using the given error message, please contact me via discord on UjanRoy#5662. Your help will be helpful. Thanks

````
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:659:15)       
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:458:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:902:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:111:5)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\commands\ping.js:8:3)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\index.js:52:3) {
  requestBody: { files: [], json: { type: 4, data: [Object] } },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Interaction has already been acknowledged.',
    code: 40060
  },
  code: 40060,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1031829409973403659/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTAzMTgyOTQwOTk3MzQwMzY1OTpZQnZrakpkN1N1ZUVFT3E0elFCRmFrTmJlZzJ2ejcwZmpjYWJwREdrNGoyYk84alVaSWJQZkRRQUw2OW5VOFlsaVo3YkMyQ1pJb2dtMENRRHNUU1FyaXE4S1VYQzYxdXcxVFB3U2M3SGJ0eEZ0MGNPRzJQQ1FRT0FrZ1RIZ3JFYQ/callback'
}
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:102:46)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ujan\Desktop\Folder\urionbot\index.js:55:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21) {
  code: 'InteractionAlreadyReplied'
}```
````

Comment: Please Include the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Error `Interaction has already been acknowledged` happens when you try to reply to the interaction that you already replied, and you can fix it by using `.editReply()` after you `.reply()` the interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the guide from discord.js, you'll need to remember to remove the events you left in `index.js` that you moved in to `ready.js` and `interactionCreate.js`. At least, that was the issue for me. Forgot to relocate the events once I'd move them out of main `index.js`